# Batch Processing in Node.js POST Request

Tags: node.js, async-await, request, settimeout

I am writing to inform that I have a request where i need to send few request items in a batch of 40  items and the next batch has to be processed after a break of 10 seconds. I have changed the params and suppose If I run,

```
const request = require('request'); let options = {   'method': 'POST',   'url': 'https://somewebsite.com/uk/v1/process/day_assignments.json',   'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer *'   },   body: JSON.stringify([{"officer_id":6789,"major_id":[345]}, {"officer_id":1357,"major_id":[678]}, {"officer_id":9135,"major_id":[901]}, {"officer_id":2468,"major_id":[234]},])

}; request(options, (error, response) => {   if (error) throw new Error(error);   console.log(response.body);
```

and then after 10 seconds it should process:

```
const request = require('request'); let options = {   'method': 'POST',   'url': 'https://somewebsite.com/uk/v1/process/day_assignments.json',   'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer *'   },   body: JSON.stringify([{"officer_id":0123,"major_id":[123]}, {"officer_id":4567,"major_id":[456]}, {"officer_id":8901,"major_id":[789]}, {"officer_id":2345,"major_id":[012]}])

}; request(options, (error, response) => {   if (error) throw new Error(error);   console.log(response.body);
```

I am new to node.js and how can I process this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to use setInterval

Answer (score 0):

follow this 
call 1st request 
in the first request callback use settimeout for 10 sec. 
in settimeout callback call the 2nd request.

Comment: I have like 100s of batches to process, any optimal solution?

Comment: write a for loop and wait for 10 sec before processing next batch
for i in [batch jobs ]
     process i job
     wait for 10 sec.